# Asp.net Button disable value from Sql field

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

The title may not be the best description but i would like help with having the button be disabled depending on which user click on it.

I know I should put the connection string in the `web.config` and I will but I'm not getting this button to work.

The `HasRows` yest looks if there is a row but i might do this wrong.

I have 3 rows in the table and  with only one row = 'reports' all 3 users can still click the Button?

Can anyone help me here?

```
Protected Sub LeftMenuBarReportsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LeftMenuBarReportsButton.Click

    Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
    Dim sqCmd As New SqlCommand      
    Dim sqlreader As SqlDataReader    

    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = ....;Database=......;User ID=......;Password=...."   'SQL Connection String

    sqCmd.Connection = sqlconn
    sqlconn.Open()
    sqCmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserID,Password,Role FROM UserCredentials WHERE Role = 'Reports'"
    sqlreader = sqCmd.ExecuteReader

    If sqlreader.HasRows Then

        Response.Redirect("Reports.aspx")

    Else
        Dim click As Button = sender
        click.Enabled = False
        LeftMenuBarReportsButton.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        LeftMenuBarReportsButton.Text = "Access Denied"
    End If

    sqlreader.Close()
    sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to check each time they click? It requires a lot of network delay and things while the user waits for it to resolve. You might want to make a public "hasAccess" boolean and refresh it later. But, I don't know your setup though.

Comment: Yes the server is a test server so that is fine and i would like to find out what im doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you referring to the button through `sender`?  Just below, you're referencing it by `LeftMenuBarReportsButton`.   As a side-note, and someone correct me if I'm wrong... Since you're redirecting before your conneciton is closed, this could end up filling up your connection pool.

Comment: As for your question, you are only checking at the time in your SQL if you have users which have the Role 'Reports', you are not checking any of them to be the current user. You are right that your connection string should be in the web.config, but your data layer shouldn't be inside your presentation layer either, everything concerning the DB should be outside of the presentation layer, access to the data layer, should go over an entity layer and a logic layer.